# How can prevent reapeating this piece of code 10 times?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use 10 of the grids like below in my XAML, each time with other binding sources.
Do I have to repeat (copy/paste) this code 10 times or is there a better way? (template?)

```
<Grid>                               
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <TextBox
           Style="{StaticResource TBGrid}"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Text="{Binding ...}" />
     <Label
          Style="{StaticResource TBLabel}"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Content="{Binding....}" />
</Grid>
```

Now I have this code, with help from commenters, and it seems to work:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MVVMCable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ArrowLabel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ArrowLabel : UserControl
    {
        public ArrowLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;  //  <==== this must be added, seemingly.
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "TextBoxText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ArrowLabel),
                new PropertyMetadata("")
            );

        public string TextBoxText
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "LabelText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ArrowLabel),
                new PropertyMetadata("")
            );

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(LabelTextProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MVVMCable.ArrowLabel"
    x:Name="MyArrowLabel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="137.8"
    d:DesignWidth="279.2">
    <Grid
        Width="70"
        Height="15">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="30"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="14" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox
            Height="20"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            IsEnabled="False"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
            Width="30"
            Text="{Binding ElementName=MyArrowLabel, Path=TextBoxText}"/>
        <Label
            Height="auto"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Width="auto"
            Content="{Binding ElementName=MyArrowLabel, Path=LabelText}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I use it in my app like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MVVMCable"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:shapes="clr-namespace:MVVMCable.Views"
    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MVVMCable.MainWindow"
    .......
     <c:ArrowLabel
         Canvas.Left="10"
         Canvas.Top="6"
         TextBoxText="{Binding Cable.RHVc}"  <== error here and
         LabelText="{Binding Units[X].Display}" />   <== here
```

Error text is:

Error   2   The member "LabelText" is not recognized or is not accessible.

And after adding this.DataContext = this;, things seem to work.

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown at least 2 repetitions, and filled in the dots for the databinding. Do you use MVVM, a framework?

Answer (score 4):

Because there is going to be different `DataContext` for each, I would recommend a custom `UserControl`.

For example:

The `UserControl` itself will have the repeated XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SpecialUserControl"
    x:Name="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>                               
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <TextBox
               Style="{StaticResource TBGrid}"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=TextBoxText}" />
         <Label
              Style="{StaticResource TBLabel}"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Content="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=LabelText}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind of the `UserControl` will have two `DependencyProperties`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "TextBoxText", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(SpecialUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata("")
    );

public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return this.GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty) as string; }
    set { this.SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "LabelText", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(SpecialUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata("")
    );

public string LabelText
{
    get { return this.GetValue(LabelTextProperty) as string; }
    set { this.SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
}
```

If you notice, the `UserControl` XAML actually bind to these `DependencyProperties` for the `TextBox` and `Label` controls.

Now for usage, all you will have to do is use the defined `DependencyProperties` to bind to whatever you will like:

```
<namespace:SpecialUserControl 
    TextBoxText="{Binding ThisIsABinding}" 
    LabelText="{Binding ThisIsAnotherBinding}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction. I'll study this.

Comment: @Erik no problem! Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: hmmm.... I get an error in XAML: The member "LabelText" is not recognized or is not accessible. (same for TextBoxText). All the rest compiles OK: the UserControl XAML and its CB, only my app's XAML shows the errormessage.

Comment: @Erik I just fixed it. The dependency properties were actually missing a "P" in the name. See update. Make sure it says "Property" not "roperty"

Comment: I found that one, or rather VS2013 stumbled over it, but it does not make the error go away. Strange thing is, that I do NOT get an error on the <c:ArrowLable line. SO it does recognize the Control, i'd say, but not the DepProp's

Answer (score 0):

If the bindings could be standartized to most cases and you could switch only the context, then you should create a `UserControl`, put your content in there. And use it wherever you need instead of repeating code, just changing the DataContext they are bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom field control by dependency property. In this field control you can combine label and text box feature together. Then you can put control in the stackpanel. So, It will remove the redundant code.